# Editing a App.Config file in different domain.

Tags: c#, .net

I have following code which works fine to open an app.config file. However, the config file I need to open is from a separate application running independently than the application I am trying to read from. Any idea what would replace CurrentDomain or how to go about it. 
Thanks

```
// Load the app.config file
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way [1] you can access a different domain, by means of an `AppDomain` instance, *unless when you have created it in the first place and held on to the reference*.

That is the whole point of app domain isolation.

You can only open the other domain's app.config file, if you know its path / file name by other means as the `AppDomainSetup` instance of the other domain is not accessible to you.

[1] Debuggers, debugging APIs, your own CLR hosts, etc. aside.